# How to update row in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I have been trying for more than three days now to get my gridview in a bootstrap template to edit and subsequently update a selected row. I got the edit part finally working but I cannot seem to make the update do the job although I have used numerous hours copy/pasting various code from different sites and trying to tweak it with my own ideas. There seems to be nothing on the net about this particular issue or at least not complete.

Here is the aspx/bootstrap website part:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewFindPatient" OnRowEditing="GridViewFindPatient_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridViewFindPatient_RowUpdating" CssClass="table-responsive" runat="server" AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:boundfield datafield="insurance" headertext="Edit here:" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField Headertext="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btneditrowpat" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/editicon.gif" CommandName="Edit"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField Headertext="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnsaverowpat" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/saveicon.gif" CommandName="Update"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="4" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
public void GridViewFindPatient_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridViewFindPatient.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        string id = GridViewFindPatient.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        TextBox fName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("firstName");
        TextBox lName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("lastName");
        TextBox addr = (TextBox)row.FindControl("address");
        TextBox pCode = (TextBox)row.FindControl("postalCode");
        TextBox city = (TextBox)row.FindControl("city");
        TextBox tel = (TextBox)row.FindControl("telephone");
        TextBox email = (TextBox)row.FindControl("email");
        TextBox patSSN = (TextBox)row.FindControl("patientSSN");
        CheckBox ins = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("insurance");


        care4uDataContext db = new care4uDataContext();

        var patSSNquery = (from pat in db.Patients
                          where pat.patientId == Convert.ToInt32(id)
                          select pat).First();

        patSSNquery.firstName = fName.Text;
        patSSNquery.lastName = lName.Text;
        patSSNquery.address = addr.Text;
        patSSNquery.postalCode = Convert.ToInt32(pCode.Text);
        patSSNquery.city = city.Text;
        patSSNquery.telephone = tel.Text;
        patSSNquery.email = email.Text;
        patSSNquery.insurance = Convert.ToBoolean(ins.Text);



        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }

        GridViewFindPatient.EditIndex = -1;
        PopulatePatGridview();
    }
```

I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong here in regards to the `RowUpdating` command. I tried various combinations but without success. Hoping that someone here can shed light on this.

PS: The latest error I got when using the above code was "out of databounds" but this isn't the major issue here if anyone should wonder, just a result of the latest trial & error on my part.

> Exception thrown with the above code:
>
> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233086   Message=Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter.
>   Parametername: index   Source=mscorlib   ParamName=index   StackTrace:
>          at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKeyArray.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          at care4u1guib.patientedit.GridViewFindPatient_RowUpdating(Object sender,
>   GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) i c:\Users\X\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\care4u1guib\care4u1guib\patientedit.aspx.cs:linje 62
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowUpdating(GridViewUpdateEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Comment: Does the debugger get in at GridViewFindPatient_RowUpdating? Are you getting error? Your question lacks information. Please add what is happening and what are the solutions you've tried.

Comment: @jomsk1e - With the present code I am getting an error that says "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index". I didn't get this error before the last change though. The edit command would work but the update would only either reload the page without the gridview results or just repost the whole page with the gridview. The gridview was never updated so far. If any more questions, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I hear you and I agree to the fullest in regards to the learning procedure. Also I was born long before the internet as we know it existed. I'd love to learn from someone that knows rather than faulty stubs from the net. However my biggest challenge is finding someone/something that can give me just that knowledge. I'd like to be more precise but I don't know what else to say. I supplied the above code and hoped that a skilled eye would find the mishap. I changed the line with "int id = etc." to this string "id = GridViewFindPatient.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()" but...

Comment: @JohnSaunders - ...now the program throws the following exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index". I can't see why it isn't working. I am converting to the right datatype as far as the setup is concerned. Will happily provide you with more details. Just gotta know what you are interested in.

Comment: First, whenever you think about exceptions, think about the _full exception_. If you catch the exception or see it in the debugger, then look at `ex.ToString()`. That's also generally what you should post when you share the exception. Second, once you see what line causes the exception, set a breakpoint before that line in the debugger. examine the value of the index, and determine the length of the array or collection.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - The line throwing the exception is as mentioned last the "string id = GridViewFindPatient.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();" with the afore mentioned error code. I used debugger + page inspector as you asked. After thrown exception "row" shows DataItem null, DataItemIndex 2, RowIndex 2, RowState Edit. "id" only shows "id null". The first part is correct since I selected row three in gridview for editing. The last part I don't get. Any ideas or do you need more information?

Comment: Please update your question. There is no "`string id =`" anywhere in your question. And I didn't mean to use the Page Inspector. I mean use the debugger and set a breakpoint on the method that's throwing the exception, then single-step until the exception happens, looking at the "Autos" window on each step to see how things change. Also, you still haven't posted the full exception.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I updated the question with the present code including the full exception thrown that was copy/pasted from Visual Studio. The string thingy was only a slighty trial that I mentioned in my second post to you. In regards to using page inspector - I use a login site in this project that is set as the startpage thus I need some sort of output window + it seemed the easiest when using debugger at the same time. I have looked at the autos window while debugging but the outcome is still the same. It crashes at the `string id =` line. Please see edited question for detailed exception.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Just to clarify the sentence about the "debugging outcome still being the same". The same values that I described in my fourth answer to you are still shown in the autos window. The "id" is still holding the value of null when the crash occurs + all the "row" values are still the same. By the way - my Page_Load contains `if (!IsPostBack) {PopulatePatGridview();}` function. That's just to populate the gridview at first load of page but I was wondering if that could create issues here. In case you need the code for that function, please let me know.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Was this enough information?